# Two Buttons. Above each other. Over whole screen

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I just like two buttons above each other with no margins. This seems like an easy task, but I am new to iOS and I wasted too much time now. I tried dozens of contraints but it never went out well. I always ended up with setting the leading Spaces to -24 and having marings above and beneath the buttons. I am using xcode6, iOS8.1 and storyboard. My app is landscape only. Can someone please teach me what to do?

The buttons should look like seen in this picture: Fullscreen, no margins and Button1 should reach unter the statusbar![image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll outline the steps:

- `Pin` Button 1 to `0` spacing on **Left, Right, Top**
- `Pin` Button 2 to `0` spacing on **Left, Right, Bottom**
- Select both buttons, then `Pin` `heights equally`

(You can access pin either from the Editor tool bar in the top menu, or from the second icon in the constraints area)

[image]

The thing with constraints and auto layout is that you only need enough constraints to let the app calculate where elements should be at all times. You might be able to get away with less constraints.

To get remove the borders, you need to change the button Type in IB from `System` to `Custom`, then you can drag and alter the margins to remove them. Following that you will need to **update constraints** on the buttons.

Comment: how to pin a button to an edge?

Comment: It is not working. It looks like a margin is set somewhere else. I followed your instructions and there is a double margin between both buttons. marings left and right to the edges of both buttons and one on the top of button1. The only place where no margin is, is below button2

Comment: do you mean the text in the button?

Comment: No the button itself. By button is a picture, so I can see clearly where it ends and starts

Comment: set the button `Type` as `Custom`, then you can drag the margins. after you drag the margins update the constraints in Editor/Resolve Autolayout Issues. Button type is set to `System` by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70071/discussion-between-moobi-and-chris).

Comment: Additional to your answer I also added a constraint "same heights" to the buttons and set the constraints to the edges to -24, but one to +24. This all makes no sense but it looks good now.